# LINQ Query returning null, extracting object attribute value from JSON file

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to extract a country abbreviation for a specific country name from a JSON file. Here is my JSON file:

```
[
 {
   "country": "Iceland",
   "abbr": "IS"
 },
 {
   "country": "Kosovo",
   "abbr": "KS"
 },
 {
   "country": "Belgium",
   "abbr": "BE"
  },...
]
```

Here is the model for country:

```
public class Country
{
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string abbr { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the following LINQ query for extracting the given abbreviation and this is returning null for the variable abbreviation:

```
 var abbreviation = from n in countries
                    where n.country.Equals(selectedCountry)
                    select n.abbr;
```

I able to retrieve the list of coutries (first line of LINQ query, I checked using the debugger) and I have selectectedCountry equal to "Iceland". So I am suspecting the problem is coming from the last 2 lines of the LINQ query, I am not really familiar with LINQ queries so I don't know if this is legal. I am operating on one single data table as well so i don't know if that means I should be using a specific type of query.

Comment: What's the value of the selectedCountry, make sure it does not contain spaces and it should be case sensitive.

Comment: This is totally up to how you parse the JSON.

Comment: The value of the selected country is "Iceland", which is present in my JSON file

Comment: The selected country does or does not contain the double quotes? Which is to say, is the value Iceland or "Iceland"? Because when deserialized from your JSON, the value is likely to be Iceland and not "Iceland"... The code that everyone will want to see is the code that is populating and passing selectedCountry to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were debugging it I would set breakpoints before and after the query to see what the data it's referring to looks like.

```
var abbreviation = (from n in countries
                    where n.country
                    .Equals(selectedCountry, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) // ignore case
                    select n.abbr).FirstOrDefault(); // no duplicates expected
```

This is not tested but should work.

Comment: thanks that worked for me! Now I am trying to do another LINQ query but this one should return an IEnumerable<Airport>:                           IEnumerable<Airport> EuropeanAirports = IEnumerable <Airport>((from n in airports
  where n.iso.Equals(abbreviation, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                                    select n).FirstOrDefault());                                             The casting does not work do you know how I could make this LINQ query return an IENUMERABLE

Comment: FirstOrDefault() returns an object of type Airport. To return IEnumerable you would want to leave that off.

Comment: @Mouna You need to spend more time reading the documentation of code that you are actually calling.

Comment: I just tried it and it is returning null, here is the query I wrote:  IEnumerable<Airport> EuropeanAirports = from n in airports
                                    where n.iso.Equals(abbreviation, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                                    select n;                                                                                     I debugged this code andn everything is right; airports contains the right things; abbreviation is populated right. I debugged the code using var and it returned one object within the list, I suspect it returned the first ite

Comment: Maybe what you're really after is a List<Airport> instead? In that case, replace FirstOrDefault() with ToList() and Replace IEnumerable with List. It's not going to process the query unless you do something with it.